# how to avoid duplicate value from .each method

Tags: jquery

Append table code

```
var tr = '<tr id="trdata" ><td class="code" >'+item_name+'</td><td class="itemname" >'+item_name2+'</td> <td class="qty" >'+qty+'</td><td class="rate" >'+rate+'</td> <td class ="grand">'+total+'</td> <td><button type = "button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" >Remove</button></td></tr>';
$('tbody').append(tr);
    $("#form2")[0].reset();
}
```

Value getting code

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var code      = [];
    var itemname  = [];
    var qty       = [];
    var rate      = [];
    var grand     = [];

    $('.code').each(function(){code.push($(this).text());});
    $('.itemname').each(function(){itemname.push($(this).text());});
    $('.qty').each(function(){qty.push($(this).text());});
    $('.rate').each(function(){rate.push($(this).text());});
    $('.grand').each(function(){grand.push($(this).text());});
});
```

in my console showing duplicate value

```
"console.log(code);"
[]
0: "3"
1: "3"
length: 2
```

how to avoid this duplication its also inserted in my database while using the insert query

Comment: Don't you need the values to correspond between all the arrays? If you suppress duplicates in one array, it won't match up correctly if the other arrays don't have duplicates.

Comment: Why are you making 5 different arrays, why not a single array of objects like `{code: x, itemname: y, qty: z, ...}`?

Comment: You can use `INSERT IGNORE` in the database to prevent duplicating keys.

Comment: @Barmar clearly that depends on the database being used, which has not been specified by OP

Comment: @freedomn-m It's practically always MySQL, so I'm willing to comment on that assumption. I assume other databases have something analogous.

Comment: `$query .='
      INSERT INTO kot_billdetl (ks_billno,ks_itcode,ks_qty,ks_rate,
      ks_amount,ks_net,ks_billdate,ks_billed_user)
      VALUES ("'.$billno.'","'.$code_clean.'","'.$qty_clean.'","'.$rate_clean.'","'.$grand_clean.'","'.$grand_clean.'","'.$billdate.'","'.$user.'");
      ';
    }
   }

   if($query != '')
   {
    if(multi_query($query))
    { 
     echo 'Bill Saved';
    }else
    { 
     echo 'error';
    }`

Comment: yes mysql this was the code for inserting

Comment: `$.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{code:code,itemname:itemname,qty:qty,rate:rate,grand:grand,billno:billno,billdate:bill_date,customer:customer,totalamount:totl_amnt,pay_type:pay},
        success:function(data)
        {

        alert(data);
        //window.location.reload();
        $("td").text("");
        for(var i=2; i<=count; i++)
        {
        $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
        }
        $("#form")[0].reset();
        }
        });`

Comment: through ajax am posting to  the  'save.php' page

Comment: @Barmar good guess, I'm just asking you qualify in future, eg "For MySQL you can use...".  Personally, I've never used MySQL and there's no equivalent in what I use.

Comment: @ajtih Don't try to put long code blocks in comments. Edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @freedomn-m The equivalent for any DB would be `INSERT INTO table (<cols>) SELECT <vals> FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE <primaryKeyColumn> = <primaryKeyValue>)`

Comment: @Barmar all the array have duplicate values showing

Comment: use the below code and see: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#save').click(function(){
  var code      = [];
  $('.code').each(function(){
   var checkval = $.inArray($(this).text(), code);
   if (checkval == -1) {
     code.push($(this).text());
   }
  });
  console.log(code);
 });
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test `.includes()`

```
$('.code').each(function(){
    if (!code.includes($(this).text()) {
        code.push($(this).text());
    }
});
```

But if you need to keep all the arrays in sync, you should use one loop over the rows, rather than separate loops for each field.

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var curCode = $(this).find(".code").text();
    if (!code.includes(curCode)) {
        code.push(curCode);
        itemname.push($(this).find(".itemname").text());
        qty.push($(this).find(".qty").text());
        rate.push($(this).find(".rate").text());
        grand.push($(this).find(".grand").text());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, FYI - includes does not support in IE. So I did not use includes.you can use the inArray and check.

Comment: I've given up on writing answers that are dumbed down for IE. If you need a polyfill, you knew where to get it.